# Ошибка при обращении к vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

когда бот неактивен какое-то время, выскакивает подобная ошибка. что делать?

Лог: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=35)`

Comment: использовать вебсокеты

Comment: @dmitry klemenkov
можно, пожалуйста, подробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватывайте ошибку и запрашивайте снова

```
import requests

connect_loop = True
while connect_loop:
    try:  
        response = requests.request()
        connect_loop = False
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException: # любая ошибка requests
        print('ConnectionError')
        continue
```